# Looking for next match (integer) in list of strings

Tags: c#, string, list, search, numbers

I have a problem finding the next integer match in a list of strings, there are some other aspects to consider:

- single string contains non relevant trailing and leading chars
- numbers are formatted "D6" example 000042
- there are gaps in the numbers
- the list is not sorted, but it could be if there is a fast way to ignore the leading chars

Example:

- abc-000001.file
- aaac-000002.file
- ab-002010.file
- abbc-00003.file
- abbbc-00004.file
- abcd-00008.file
- abc-000010.file
- x-902010.file

The user input is 7 => next matching string would be abcd-000008.file

My attempt is :

```
int userInput = 0;
int counter = 0;
string found = String.Empty;
bool run = true;

while (run)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strList.Count; i++)
    {
        if(strList[i].Contains((userInput + counter).ToString("D6")))
        {
            found = strList[i];
            run = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    counter++;
}
```

It's bad because it's slow and it can turn into a infinite loop. But I really don't know how to do this (fast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse numbers from strings with [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) and created a sorted collection which you can search with `Where` clause:

```
var strings = new[] { "abc-000001.file", "x-000004.file"};
var regP = "\\d{6}"; // simplest option in my example, maybe something more complicated will be needed
var reg = new Regex(regP);
var collection = strings
    .Select(s =>
    {
        var num = reg.Match(s).Captures.First().Value;
        return new { num = int.Parse(num), str = s};
    })
    .OrderBy(arg => arg.num)
    .ToList();

var userInput = 2;
var res = collection
    .Where(arg => arg.num >= userInput)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.str; // x-000004.file
```

P.S.

How `9002010`, `0000010`, `0002010` should be treated? Cause they have 7 characters. Is it `[9002010, 10, 2010]` or `[900201, 1, 201]`?

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake creating the examples, it's meant to be 6 characters, corrected it. Your answer looks promising, I will try it out. Thank you

Comment: @nanu_nana glad it helped. You can change `var regP = "\\d{6,}"` to `var regP = "\\d{6}"` in your code then (fixed in the answer also).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want regex, you can do something like that:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>
{
    "abc-000001.file",
    "aaac-000002.file",
    "ab-0002010.file",
    "abbc-000003.file",
    "abbbc-000004.file",
    "abcd-000008.file"
};
int input = 7;

var converted = strings.Select(s => new { value = Int32.Parse(s.Split('-', '.')[1]), str = s })
                        .OrderBy(c => c.value);

string result = converted.FirstOrDefault(v => v.value >= input)?.str;

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: I think I did not make it clear enough in my initial question, the leading and trailing chars could be anything (that will not break the D6 format of the numbers). Sorry for that.